Maui - Net 8 => Filepicker pick cancel crashes the app. fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 or Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR)
I am using maui for not so complicated android app. Using .net 8 and for debug device I use Huawei device running APK 29 also samsung flip running APK 34.
Also I should mention that I am using mvvm pattern and the tool i am using for it is community tool kit.

The problem:

When you use Filepicker to select file( either using Filepicker.Default.PickAsync() static method or using a requesting as a service from constructor.
This is how i injected the service:
//Edited. Transient to Singleton
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFilePicker>((e) => FilePicker.Default); 

When I try to pick file everything goes how it is supposed to. But when you cancel the select file process and go back to app, app crashes with no exception and nothing. I see the error as either fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 or Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR). I have searched those errors and those indicates some kind of address issues.
I shared vs 2022 output information and the Huawei phone's logcat when error happened.
I styled the error part of the logs to bold. I hope it is understandable.
What did i tried to fix the problem or find the causes of the error:

I tried bypassing mvvm pattern and I called filepicker.pickasync() inside clicked event of a button using either static method or injected service. No luck.
Tried the first way on several different pages in case navigation causes a problem. Nope!!
I tried mediapicker instead of filepicker to see if the file picker the problem. Nope! Mediapicker causes the same problem.
But if I create new maui project and use the file picker or media picker as either static method or the injected service on both code behind  clicked event and mvvm pattern's command there is no problem. works perfectly.

So it seems problem is in my project. But what the problem is or what causes the problem i couldn't figure it out.
What do you think?
PS: sorry for my english.
Edit: How I call filepicker
[RelayCommand]
private async Task OpenFile()
{
    try 
    {
        var result = await openFile.PickAsync(new PickOptions
        {
            PickerTitle = localization.GetLocalizationKeyValue("KmlKmzFilePickerTitle"),
            FileTypes = new FilePickerFileType(new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
            {
                {DevicePlatform.Android, new []{ "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml", "application/vnd.google-earth.kmz", "text/plain" } }
            })
        });  
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}

Edit:
I tried running on UI tread. Same problem. Also checked if code running on main thread with MainThread.IsMainThread . Yes code is on mainthread also I put breakpoint and app never exits openFile.PickAsync() method. It doesn't even hit the catch block. In openFile.PickAsync() method app crashes and gives an output These lines:

[m.andromeda.gi] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 19037(1444KB)
AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 38% free, 37MB/61MB, paused
151us total 110.722ms []
Assertion at /__w/1/s/src/mono/mono/mini/interp/interp.c:2106,
condition `context->stack_pointer  context-stack_end' not met
[libc] Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 26407 (m.andromeda.gis), pid 26407 (m.andromeda.gis)


Would need to see actual code around how you are calling the FilePicker and checking responses. For a start FilePicker.Default is a Singleton so you should be registering the service as AddSingleton, not AddTransient. Transient means "construct a new instance for each request for a dependency". I don't think anything good would come out of feeding a Singleton to AddTransient.

Tried singleton. Same response. App crashes. Also I edit my question and added code block how i call file picker as you requested.

According to the documentation, a user cancellation will be handed as an exception. So depending on android vs. Windows vs. IOS you can, and need to handle exceptions, not bubble them. "Note that this method may re-throw platform specific exceptions that occurred during file picking." So their example just shows them eating exceptions with a comment. "// The user canceled or something went wrong".  So no, I wouldn't throw(ex); to bubble an exception. Try just eating it (do nothing) or console writing it and see if the app still crashes. Also be sure you are running this on the UI thread.

I edited my question. I deleted long output and logcat information and put some summary. Also checked if code runs on mainthread. And I never hit the catch block.

Strange.. What happens if you forgo the dependency and just use await FilePicker.Default.PickAsync(...)?  How is OpenFile being called? I see it's marked as a relaycommand, is this wired to an event handler or being called explicitly by code?

FilePicker.Default.PickAsync(...) won't do any difference. Already checked. OpenFile command is being called by the custom view. Even if I call Filepicker from button's clicked eventhandler or from command property it will give the same error. Already checked those situations. I have never been this much clueless. :)

I was thinking if there is a way to make user the pick a file forcefully or pick some file behind the door without letting the user know 'A' file is picked. Then discard the file. Is it possible? Because if I pick any file app won't crash. This is not a solution but it solves my problem right now. Is that possible?

So if you remove the throw(ex); from your exception handler, and just have catch() { } does the application still crash?  If the same picker code works in a new MAUI project on the devices without crashing then there may be some form of related dependency mismatch with your old project. Look at what files are in the two deployments, check versions. Try a full clean, erasing all /bin /obj etc. output folders and a fresh build. Check all dependencies to see if any have switched to hard-coded paths instead of Nuget etc.

So if you remove the throw(ex); from your exception handler, and just have catch() { } does the application still crash? Yes..  Definetly something wrong with my project. But what? I couldn't figure it out. I did deleting bin obj folders, clean build, fresh build. I did all of it. Thank you by the way. Ypu spend yoour time to help me. I know this kind of errors to find ourself. specific ones. Anyway.. Thanks for trying to help. If i find out what it is i will post the solution. Again thank you so much for your precious time to try to find a solution.

Have you tested it on other devices, and does this problem happen as well? And how can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

Sorry for the this much delay. I was busy with other projects. Like I said befoore try catch block wont catch the exception. When cancel picking file procedure TaskCanceledException was thrown as doc mentioned. Thats why it is in the try catch block. But catch section of the try catch block wont catch the xception. But I succeded catch some other way.

`private void CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException(object? sender, System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)
{
}` I used this method to catch the exception in App.xaml.cs file. The first exception is taskcanceled exception. But later on Android.Views.InflateException was thrown couple of times then app crashes. This was I gathered so far.

Ok. I checked how FilePicker works at [link]https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Essentials/src/FilePicker/FilePicker.android.cs  It uses IntermediateActivity. [link]https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/3992a45f2a00d20222963fc959f3568239449bb9/src/Essentials/src/Platform/IntermediateActivity.android.cs#L15 I took that class and put my project. And I coded native platform File picker. Used that IntermediateActivity. I get the same problem when this line run task.TaskCompletionSource.TrySetCanceled(); in IntermediateActivity class.

I gave up. I wrote some native platform code for file pick. And talking to myself :)

This is expected behavior like mentioned in Documentation and tutorials. You need wrap the PickAsync() call inside a try Catch Block.
   try
   {
     await Filepicker.PickAysnc()
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
     //Do stuff if user cancels picker
   }


It is inside try-catch block. I didn't mention that specifically.  Try-catch won't catch the error.

Which platform is this specifically happening? and also have you tried with other devices?

Android. for debug purposes the devices I use are Huawei running APK 29 also samsung flip running APK 34.
